# How should number of epochs be needed when fitting a model?

Tags: python

My training set has 2000 samples and validation set has 700 samples.

How big should batch size and number of epochs be when fitting a model to optimize the val_acc? Is there any sort of rule of thumb to use based on data input size?

Comment: You didn't even say what are you training? What sort of architecture...What is the data is it images, audio, numeric data? And no there is not "mathematical formula", which would tell you explicitly that it should be "x" epochs for "y" model.

Comment: image data,using vgg 19

Comment: In general you should have the dataset divided into 3 parts: training, test, validation. The training is sort of trial and error. I'd start from small number of epochs (training will be quick then) and observe metrics. Depending on what is important to you: precision, recall, F1-score, something else. And I'd increase number of epochs in case of underfitting. Batch size depends on vram of your gpu and how many of those images can you fit there, but even if you have lot of memory too big batch size will make the net "memorize" your dataset. It's a lot of knowledge to get through honestly.